# How to save a searchable and queryable json document in Postgres?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, database-design, nosql

Receiving a Person's profile as JSON. How can I `model` it in a way it every value of this JSON document is searchable? 

Not only json document needs to be searchable. It should also be queryable like "find all the persons who like Tarantino movies".
 I can define this document in a relational model with one to many relationships. But this approach wouldn't allow free text search from the client side.
Is there a better way to handle such scenarios?
 Document look like this:

```
{  
   "name":"FirstN LastN",
   "photo":nicephoto.jpg,
   "location":"Boston, MA",
   "contacts":[  
      {  
         "type":"phone",
         "value":"701290012734"
      },
      {  
         "type":"email",
         "value":"test@test.com"
      }
   ],
   "movies":[  
      {  
         "name":"The Godfather",
         "director":"Francis Ford Coppola",
         "releaseYear":"1972",
         "favQuote":"I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse. Okay?"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Pulp Fiction",
         "director":"Quentin Tarantino",
         "releaseYear":"1994",
         "favQuote":"Just because you are a character doesn't mean that you have character."
      }
   ],
   "school":null,

}
```

Comment: As a solution approach (not a full answer, I'm afraid) : try a full relational schema plus a direct indexing on the json.

Comment: What do you mean by `direct indexing on the json`?

Comment: At first,I thought of plain full-text indexing, but that won't help much because it's for natural language only. Turns out, postgres has JSON support built-in :  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 0):

"find all the persons who like Tarantino movies" needs to be written or converted in SQL like:

```
select persons->>'name' from jdoc,json_array_elements(jdoc.persons->'movies') movies where movies->>'director' ~ 'Tarantino';
```

other selection criteria can be modeled in similar way.

Requires Postgres 9.3 or later

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/652eb/10

to the question "how to save":

```
create table jdoc (persons json);
insert into jdoc values ('{  
   "name":"FirstN LastN",
   "photo":"nicephoto.jpg",
   "location":"Boston, MA",
  "contacts":[  
      {  
         "type":"phone",
         "value":"701290012734"
      },
      {  
         "type":"email",
         "value":"test@test.com"
      }
   ],
   "movies":[  
      {  
         "name":"The Godfather",
         "director":"Francis Ford Coppola",
         "releaseYear":"1972",
         "favQuote":"Im gonna make him an offer he cant refuse. Okay?"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Pulp Fiction",
         "director":"Quentin Tarantino",
         "releaseYear":"1994",
         "favQuote":"Just because you are a character doesnt mean that you have character."
      }
   ], 
   "school":null

}')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be [looking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWOR) for `FLWOR`:

```
   for $d in doc("depts.xml")//deptno
   let $e := doc("emps.xml")//employee[deptno = $d]
   where count($e) >= 10
   order by avg($e/salary) descending
   return
     <big-dept>
        { $d,
           <headcount>{count($e)}</headcount>,
           <avgsal>{avg($e/salary)}</avgsal>
        }
     </big-dept>
```

although it doesn't look like `Postgres` has [plans](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4B7B269F.6090708@dunslane.net) to support `Xquery`.